# @fontface not installing correctly

Tags: css, font-face

I have just brought a web fontface to use for the first time. I have uploaded it our testing server and it works on all the machines in the office except for one laptop.

After discovering that laptop didn't work, I did a test on crossbrowsertesting.com across all platforms and discovered it wasn't appearing on any of them.

I then uploaded the mywebsfontkit folder with the instructions of how to install the webfont to my server and did another crossbrowser check and discovered that font started to work on some of the browsers yet when I try put it into my own page it fails.

I have tried several ways to make it work. 
1 - I put the full url path to the font in - nothing happened
2 - I have put the webfonts in the root folder as well as root folder of my server
3 - I have tried calling the font museo in different ways i.e font-family: 'Museo' or font-family: 'Museo-700'.

In the sample I am posting you will see that for the nav I call museo as museo-700 and that now on my machine calls arial instead and on the text in the header I am calling museo as font-family: 'Museo'. I understand that the font it won't work on all browsers but I can't figure out why it will work in one file and not the other.

I have also added in to my .htaccess file
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

The style sheet that holds the fonts is been called as follows

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/type.css" />
```

the stylesheet that has the fonts

```
 @font-face {font-family: 'Museo-900';src: url('webfonts/23C024_0_0.eot');src: url('webfonts/23C024_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/23C024_0_0.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/23C024_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');}


 @font-face {font-family: 'Museo-700';src: url('webfonts/23C024_1_0.eot');src: url('webfonts/23C024_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/23C024_1_0.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/23C024_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');}


 @font-face {font-family: 'Museo-500';src: url('webfonts/23C024_2_0.eot');src: url('webfonts/23C024_2_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/23C024_2_0.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/23C024_2_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

and how i am calling the font for the nav and header

```
    #nav ul li {
float: left;
position: relative;
color:#000;
font-family: 'Museo-700', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
}

    .title-900 {
font-family: 'Museo-900', Arial, sans-serif !important;
font-weight: normal;
font-size:18px;
line-height:20px;
color:#9BC255;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `@font-face` sections you have called the the loaded fonts `Museo-900`, `Museo-700`, `Museo-500` and you **must use the same font family** in the regular directives, like:

```
font-family: "Museo-900", Arial, sans-serif !important;
```

Other than this, I cannot see anything else in your sandbox that might cause such a problem.

Comment: Thanks I have just realised too that I have spelt Museo incorrectly as well so that is not going to help me either!

Comment: I have corrected the way that I am calling Museo but I am still having the same issues of when I test across multiple browsers not one is showing up with Museo.

Comment: @kas, I don't see any change there. You still have `Museo-?00` in your `type.css` file, and `font-family: 'Museo', ...` in your `bhc_retail.css` file. As I said, **you have to use the same font-family string** to get the web-font work.

Comment: sorry about that - I thought I had overwritten the stylesheet but it hadn't copied across properly. I just did a clean upload and tested it with crossbrowser tester again and it is all working wonderfully now. Thanks so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of reference for future reading. Following are the generic approaches that can be helpful to resolve this type of issues:

a. First check whether your css framework files load before your custom css file. Your custom css file must load after framework/widget css files to have higher precedence.

b. Font property is an inheritable CSS property. It means that if you have applied it on the body tag then all the html elements will inherit it from body tag provided no intermediate element have different value of font-family property specified. Make sure that no such element exists in your DOM. Also, your font-file should show up in the network tab with 200 status.

c. Calculate the specificity of the font family property of the elements. Sometimes, we do not get expected results even after downloading of the new fonts because our font-family has lower specificity(precedence).